# missing border line when using android relative layout

Tags: android, android-layout, layout, android-relativelayout

I have this android layout xml:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

   <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="#70a5b3" 
        android:layout_above="@+id/skipIcon"/>

    <com.m.view.text.MyTextView
        style="@style/textOnBg"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/skipIcon"
        android:text="Skip"
        android:textStyle="normal" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@id/skipIcon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:src="@drawable/signup_skip_icon" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

and I want to create this layout

[image]

but my xml doesn't show the border line. How can I fix this?

Comment: Can you post your complete xml of this layout??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <View
        android:id="@+id/border_line"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:background="#70a5b3" />

    <com.m.view.text.MyTextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/skipIcon"
        android:text="Skip"
        android:textStyle="normal" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@id/skipIcon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/border_line"
        android:src="@drawable/signup_skip_icon" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: super! but why `android:layout_alignParentTop="true"` worked and `android:layout_above="@+id/skipIcon"` didn't?

Comment: what happens when I don't add `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` to `TextView`?

Comment: TextView always need a height and width parameters! {eclipse will prompt a error}. And i don't have an answer for ur first question, i had the same issue once, and it worked this way for me! ;-)

Answer (score 0):

try padding of 1dp in your relative layout.

Comment: didnt help. any other idea?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<RelativeLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<View
    android:id="@+id/line"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:background="#70a5b3"/>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/skipIcon"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_below="@id/line"
    android:src="@drawable/signup_skip_icon" />

<com.waze.view.text.WazeTextView
    style="@style/textOnBg"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/line"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/skipIcon"
    android:text="Skip"
    android:textStyle="normal"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```